# Does anyone know how to compile a list of words that differ by adding/removing one letter?

Tags: word-usage

Examples of couplings being cold and cod, or amber and ambler.
Any ideas on how to get a complete list of these would be much appreciated.

Comment: I imagine a 'complete list' would be fairly large, especially if you include plurals.

Comment: I don't think one of these is already premade, but I'm sure the StackOverflow community might be a better place since they specialize in computer programming (which you'll undoubtedly need to compile such a list).

Comment: And then undoubtedly the StackOverflow community would say to post it here...